# Json response gives undefined error in chrome but works in IE

Tags: json, jquery, cross-domain, undefined

Am new to ajax and cross domains and am in the dark here, i have been trying to research on the above mentioned title and it keeps pointing to cross domain error, can someone help me as to how i can fix the code to adhere to these cross domain.

here is my code:

```
function GetEmployeeInformation() {
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://localhost:8080/SampleEmpService/Employees/" + $("#txtEmpno").val(),
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              cache:false,
              dataType:"json",
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert(xhr.status);
                  alert(xhr.statusText);
                  alert(thrownError)
              },
              success: function (response) {
                  $("#divEmployeeInfo").html("");
                  $("#divEmployeeInfo").append("Id: ").append(response.Empno + "<br />");
                  $("#divEmployeeInfo").append("Name: ").append(response.Ename + "<br />");
                  $("#divEmployeeInfo").append("Salary: ").append(response.Sal + "<br />");
                  $("#divEmployeeInfo").append("Deptno: ").append(response.Deptno + "<br />");
              }
          });
      }
```

it works fine in IE but gives and undefined error in chrome.

Comment: There isn't any content in get requests, try removing `contentType`

Answer (score 0):

Use dataType="jsonp" for cross-domains. You may also need to set "crossDomain: true".